# im setting up redis deployment in kubernetes . how can i locally access the redis that i deployed in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, port, host, redis-cli

Deployed redis in my Kubernetes. How can I access that redis from the local machine
my redis-service.yaml is :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
    nodePort: 30369
  selector:
    app: redis
```

have any idea about this ?? when I try on my local machine, it shows me the error:

```
Could not connect to Redis at http://5******7:30369/:6379: Name or service not known
```

Comment: How did you deploy your cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to provide url as

> http://<your k8s ip>:<nodeport>

No need to add the targetPort in the url

Comment: when i follow this, i could see "This site can’t be reached ,refused to connect"

Comment: are you using redis cli to connect ? can you try 
redis-cli -h<host> -p <port>